# Python start on ''silent load''

Tags: python

How do I get my Python project to start in ''silent load'' after the person login? I want only the part to appear for a person to enter login and password, and then the project starts in '' silent load '' without showing anything on the screen

```
client = Client(api_key="**************", aid="******", application_secret="*************")

while True:
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

    try:
        client.login(username, password)

    except Exception as e:
        print('Username or password incorrect.')

    else:
        break


def on_release(key):
    try:
        if key == keyboard.Key.f1:
            dd.update_status_aim()
        if key == keyboard.Key.f2:
            dd.clean_up()
    except NameError:
        pass
```

Comment: You are not showing anything problematic. If you don't want anything printed to the screen, then just do not use `print` after a successfull login. Please provide more code (like a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to show the problem so that we could help.

Comment: I just want it to show the ''login'' and ''password'' part, after the login is done successfully I want the rest of the code to open without showing anything on the screen

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. What prevents you to just not `print`ing to the screen ? Could you show what is being written ?